# How do I install pysvg using easy_install?

Tags: python, svg, easy-install

I am a hardcore C programmer and I want to learn python. I am trying to write a script to generate SVG files. If I can't get this to work then I will just kill a few kittens and write C program to perform this task.

I want to use the [pysvg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysvg) library. Actually, I'm not married to that particular library. **Is there a better SVG-generator (better-documented, really) lib I should use?** Which library do you use for generating SVGs? I am creating simple SVGs (boxes and lines) from scratch.

I tried downloading the package and running `python install.py install` but I didn't really want to give it root access.

Then I relented and decided to try `sudo easy_install pysvg` and it just won't work:

```
rascher@coltrane:~$ sudo easy_install pysvg
Searching for pysvg
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pysvg/
Reading http://codeboje.de/pysvg/
No local packages or download links found for pysvg
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pysvg')

rascher@coltrane:~$ sudo easy_install pysvg==0.2.1
Searching for pysvg==0.2.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pysvg/
Reading http://codeboje.de/pysvg/
No local packages or download links found for pysvg==0.2.1
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pysvg==0.2.1')
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I install this library?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do me the favor and try it once more with easy_install. It should work now, as i uploaded the main binary zip file to PyPI.
I must admit I neglected the installation procedure of pysvg quite a lot because:
-Most users (so far) preferred to fetch the sources directly from the repository
-I never have to install it myself ;-)

But these are not really good excuses.

Best,
Kerim

Comment: Hi - it's not often you get to talk to the package maintainer himself. I'm a new at python, so I wasn't sure of the "standard" way to manage python packages, thus the question. Thanks so much for helping with this! :)

Comment: No problem, actually i am very grateful if someone finds an error. I simply don't have the resources to search for them all myself obviously. If you encounter anything else along the way, just feel free to contact me directly.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it's in pypi.  You should email the maintainer and recommend it get included.

As for installing it from source, if your python install is owned by root (it is) then you need to use sudo when running the install command.  If you're worried about what it might doing, open up the script and take a look.

Comment: Does this mean there is an error with this particular package? Or is it common for there to be a "pypi" URL for a lib that actually isn't in the repository?

Answer (score 2):

```
bin/easy_install http://pysvg.googlecode.com/files/pysvg-0.2.1.zip
```

...and ask the maintainer to [update his PyPI package metadata](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysvg/0.2.1) properly or to provide a copy on PyPI. Not uploading packages to PyPI and only having a registration with improper metadata is just bare ***** attitude of some maintainers.

Comment: Well, to be fair - it has been like that for long (the "culture" of Python packaging) and `easy_install` partially supported that culture by doing scraping of project web pages to find download links. This is further exacerbated by PyPI not willing to disallow entries with no sdists.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better SVG-generator (better-documented, really) lib I should use?

There are [a bunch of them](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/search%3asvg/) actually.

> I am creating simple SVGs (boxes and lines) from scratch

Then give [svgwrite](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/svgwrite/#about) a try. Here's an example:

```
import svgwrite
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny')
dwg.add(dwg.line((0, 0), (10, 0), stroke=svgwrite.rgb(10, 10, 16, '%')))
dwg.add(dwg.text('Test', insert=(0, 0.2), fill='red'))
dwg.save()
```

Comment: huh, svgwrite didn't show up in my (exhaustive!) google searching. Thank you for sharing activestate.com; neat! Question: what exactly is ActivePython (since apparently I have to install it to use pypm?)

Comment: @rascher - ActivePython is essentially the same as the installer you get from python.org - except it also includes valuable extras such extra documentation, PyWin32 and, most importantly, a binary package managed called PyPM that you can use to install some non-trivial modules, eg: http://code.activestate.com/pypm/matplotlib/